# jQuery: Search for div containing specific mark up

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, wysiwyg, redactor

I'm stuck with a editor that outputs `<p><br></p>` when the textfield is empty and now I want to target the divs with that none content.

I've been trying .filter, text lengths, :contains, .html and what not but can't seem to find a way to look for a `<div>` that contains that mark up.

Other `<div>` may contain that and some text which would be just normal and fine, so I will need to target the code below specifically.

```
<div>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Any idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
var $div = $("div").filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase() == "<p><br></p>";
});
```

The resulting object ($div) will be a jQuery collection of the divs you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery code :

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text) == '') {
        $(this).remove()
        // or maybe : $(this).empty()
    }
})
```